# When programs run into faults, how to write to logs and upload logs to MYSQL in signal handling functions?

Tags: c++, signal-handling

I would like to write one signal handling function for multiple programs running at different servers so that when they run into faults e.g. segmentation error SIGSEGV or SIGTERM etc, the signal handling function can produce a log and upload the contents to a central MYSQL server. This is so as to inform the administrator to identify the individual server and rectify the problem. From my research, I should be using sigaction or exception handling.

Q1: For my purpose, which (signal handling or exception handling) should I use?

Q2: I read that it is not recommended to invoke non-reentrant functions in signal handler functions e.g. printf(). In this case, how could I generate log file? Can I even be able to connect to MYSQL to upload logs in signal handling functions?

I am working with C++ and Linux. Many thanks for reading.

Comment: Have a look at using/implementing `syslogd`

Answer (score 0):

You are right, every program should implement some own reactions on signals!

Q1: Use sigaction(), it is the more elaborated as the former signal().

Q2:

- Signal handling is atomic for the whole process. You can use printf(), if you are sure, not to produce a second SIGSEGV.
- With sigaction you reserve a small amount of stack for the signal handler. This remaining stack is usefull, if the program runs into stack overflow. Make sure, that the actions of signal handler fit into this remaining stack. Writing a logfile with printf is OK, but the stack using by a networking library is not under your control.